# Mailto function is not working in Mobile view responsive

Tags: forms, html-email, email-attachments, email-validation

hey here is the code whenever my site is converted into the mobile view then mailto function is not working? can anyone suggest to me a solution to how he is works in mobile-view?

```html
    <form id="myForm" action="mailto:syedali6097@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <h2>Win</h2>
      <input name="name"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
      <br><br>
    <input name="subject"  type="text" placeholder=" Subject"> 
      <br><br>
      <!-- <label>Email:-</label> -->
      <input name="email"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Email">
      <br><br>
      <input name="number"  type="number" placeholder=" Enter Phone Number"> 
      <br><br>
      <p class="text-center">Fave Vape Flavour:-</p>
      <textarea type="text"  name="Description" size="50" rows="5" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea>
      <br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="myFunction()">
          <input type="reset" value="Reset">    
   
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ali, please learn how to properly format a question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are opening the mailto link thru the function, why not just use a link?